# what should be the depth of a convolution layer for grayscale and black and white images?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I'm going through the lecture notes here:

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

In the **first** convolution layer, we typically look at 5x5x3 where 3 refers to the RGB color space and 5x5 is the height and width of the picture.

However, if I'm looking at grayscale images it would be 5x5x1 where the last dimension would be from 0 to 1 (perfectly black to perfectly white)? Similarly, if it was even simpler with just pure black and white images, it would be 5x5x1 where the last dimension is always 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right. In case of grayscale or black and white images you have only one feature map in the input layer.